# Wireshark running on Host OS not capturing packets from VM

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, vmware, wireshark, ubuntu-18.04

I have Wireshark running on my laptop (Ubuntu 18.04), and I also have Wireshark running inside a VMware Workstation Player with a Backtrack 5 Kali Linux virtual machine image. The VM Network Connection is set to NAT. I cannot get the Wireshark that is running on the Host OS (Ubuntu) to capture pings from the VM (Kali). I can, however, capture pings from Host to VM with the Wireshark running in the VM. Host to VM pings do not show up in the Host Wireshark either while capturing from "any".

Running `ifconfig` on Host gives: (omitting `enp3s0` and `lo`)

```
vmnet1: inet 192.168.117.1
vmnet8: inet 192.168.81.1
wlp2s0: inet 192.168.1.18
```

Running `ifconfig` on VM gives: (omitting `lo`)

```
eth1: inet 192.168.81.128
```

From Host, if I run `ping 192.168.81.128`, the Wireshark running in the VM captures the packets. Here's a pair of the requests and replies:

```
No. Time        Source          Destination     Protocol        Info
199 3050.809885 192.168.81.1    192.168.81.128  ICMP            Echo (ping) request
200 3050.809914 192.168.81.128  192.168.81.1    ICMP            Echo (ping) reply
```

From VM, if I run `ping 192.168.1.18` or `ping 192.168.81.1` or `ping 192.168.117.1`,the pings come back successfully and Wireshark running in the VM captures the traffic, but the Host Wireshark captures nothing.

I've tried disabling my Host firewall with `sudo ufw disable`, but it was already disabled and changed nothing. I've also tried switching the VM Network Connection from NAT to both Bridged and Host-only, but all that resulted in were Host Destination Unreachable replies when using ping on either the Host or VM.

I've included the `vmnet1` and `vmnet8` inet addresses because they seem to be associated with the VMware Workstation Player, but they don't really seem to be relevant to my problem. But I don't know, maybe they are.

Also there are no Capture Filters or Display Filters running on either the VM Wireshark or the Host Wireshark, and the Host Wireshark is able to capture packets from other sources.

Any idea why the Host Wireshark can't capture packets sent from my Virtual Machine to my Host Machine?

Comment: Which network packets do you want to capture? Packets between host and guest or packets between guest and internet?

Comment: I want to capture packets between host and guest. I'm sending packets from guest to host.